# Email is not firing for feeditem records inserted through DataLoader

Tags: apex, batch, data-loader, feeditem

When I am Inserting feed item records through dataLoader, the standard salesforce chatter email is not firing.

But When I insert a record through UI, I am getting the mail. Also, the email is coming when doing through the Batch Apex.

I could not find the root cause of this or I am missing any setting for the same. Correct Me..!!

Comment: Is the `CreatedById` and `InsertedById` same when you are trying to load the records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the Knowledge Article [Chatter post does not trigger Chatter email notifications](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000247277&type=1)
, it is the expected behavior not to trigger emails during data migration.

> This feature is available for data migration purposes so that when you migrate posts from an external or legacy system, the chatter users are not sent emails for the migrated posts. This can be accomplished by setting the InsertedById to a different value than the CreatedById.

In your case, I assume the `InsertedById` and `CreatedById` are different and thus no emails are triggered. The article further mentions, if you still want to trigger emails, you can do so by making sure that both the ids are same.

> If you want the Chatter post to send notifications to users that have their account configured to receive notifications, make sure while inserting Chatter posts or FeedItems the CreatedById == InsertedById (that is these fields must not be different).